# each click increases the performance of its functions to one

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the button every time function runs once more. Why?

And I must click two times but I won't just one.

Try this code in google chrome .

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="one" > &nbsp Srboljub Petrovic</div>
        <input type="button" id="f" value="Klikni" onclick="f1();"></input>
        <script>
        function f1()
        {
            $("#f").click(function()
            {
                $("#one").slideUp();
                $("#one").css("border", "5px solid gray");
                $("#one").css("background-color", "red");
                $("#one").css("color","white");
                $("#one").slideDown();
            });
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: CHeck this: http://jsfiddle.net/gSYdT/ Just remove the inline call and put it in $(function()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding a click handler inside a click handler, so every time you click the button, you bind a new click event handler, and it just keeps adding up.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
            $("#f").on('click', function() {
               $("#one").slideUp(function() {
                  $(this).css({border         : "5px solid gray",
                               backgroundColor: "red",
                               color          : "white"})
                         .slideDown();
               });
            });
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="one">&nbsp Srboljub Petrovic</div>
        <input type="button" id="f" value="Klikni" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that an input element doesn't have a closing tag, and jQuery methods are chainable.
Also, to slide the element up after it slides down, use a callback.

Comment: I first try this but work on the same way.

Comment: And how it should work, actually, Srboljub(e)?

Comment: @user2152662 -  http://jsfiddle.net/q7M9p/ <- I think you need to explain better what exactly it is you're expecting ?

Comment: Try click without refresh page capoles times and you see whats happend. And first click dont do nothing and you must click second time then function work. I wont that work on the first click and dont increase function on each click for one time.

Comment: @user2152662 - did you try [***THIS LINK RIGHT HERE***](http://jsfiddle.net/q7M9p/) and does that do whatever it is you are expecting ?

Comment: @adeneo, i actually think that he wants toggle... but who knows... :)http://jsfiddle.net/WgKt7/

Comment: Thanks adeneo, this example work.

Comment: @nevermind - I was actually thinking that when I wrote the fiddle, "it seems like toggle, why would anyone slide an element down and then right up again", but nothing in the question really points to toggling, other than strange code, so who knows?

Comment: @user2152662 - Happy to help, so that was what you where looking for then !

Comment: Yes, that its it. I wont toggle I try something in jQuery and java script just simple example . Learn jQ and JScript and this suprise me when work like on my code. Thanks on more time.Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you are assigning the click handler both in your HTML and then again assigning another handler in `f1` every time it is called. If you are assigning event handlers using Javascript you shouldn't also assign them in your HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="one" > &nbsp Srboljub Petrovic</div>
    <input type="button" id="f" value="Klikni"></input>
    <script>
      $("#f").click(function(){
        $("#one").slideUp();
        $("#one").css("border", "5px solid gray");
        $("#one").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#one").css("color","white");
        $("#one").slideDown();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you bind the click function, make sure you unbind it.

```
function f1()
{
    $("#f").unbind("click").click(function()
    {
        //code
    });

}
```

Comment: Why would you do this ?

Comment: The click bind function stacks each time function f1 is called. Unbinding before binding solves this.

Comment: But then it would just be unbinding and binding a new event handler each time, as the onclick handler that calls the function is attached to the same element that the event handler is for? It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Unbind dont work for me. Function not called.

Comment: http://webroxtar.com/2011/10/solution-jquery-click-event-gets-called-twice-fires-twice/

You should just leave f1, put it in $(document).ready( and you're done